# Problema com as versões do Ionic

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Ionic não respeita a estrutura padrão do projeto inicial de acordo com as versões instaladas, eu tenho a versão 2.0.0-beta.30, node = 6.2.1 e npm 3.9.3, quando se faz a criação de um projeto ele gera o projeto com a estrutura da versão 2.2.1, com isso está muito difícil seguir algum tutorial , nada funciona direito, alguém tem uma solução para resolver isso?

Comment: Se fosse do IONIC 1 para o 2 fazia mais sentido dar erro

Comment: Como vc está gerando o projeto? Execute "ionic start projetoteste sidemenu" e veja se funciona.

Comment: Quando você gera um projeto você pode estabelecer a versão usando –V2 mais a estrutura do projeto vem sempre a mais recente

Comment: @NilsonUehara, este comando que indicou e básico para criação, ele vai gera o projeto na última versão